# how to prompt user for conditional parameters in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I have below entities

```
@menu [Pizza, Coffee, Soup]
@pizza [Pepperoni, Margherita, Farmhouse]
@coffee [Black, Espresso, Americano]
@soup [Tomato, Onion, Corn]
```

how to handle the training phrase like "please order 2 pepperoni pizza and 1 black coffee"

to fulfill this requirement I need @menu @qty and menuType so I made @menu and @qty parameters as required but how to get the menuType

menuType is dynamic if @menu is pizza then menuType will be @pizza, so I can't make the menuType as required

but if the user provides only @menu and @qty then my agent gives the response without asking for menuType because it gets the required parameters.

I want the agent to handle all the four below cases

```
CASE-1
user: order 2 pepperoni pizza
bot: ok you have ordered 2 pepperoni pizza

CASE-2
user: order 2 pizza
bot: which pizza you want?
user: pepperoni
bot: ok you have ordered 2 pepperoni pizza

CASE-3
user: order pepperoni pizza
bot: what quantity you want to order?
user: 3
bot: ok you have ordered 3 pepperoni pizza

CASE-4
user: order 2 pepperoni pizza and 1 black coffee
bot: ok you have ordered 2 pepperoni pizza and 1 black coffee
```

is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried custom follow-up intents?

Comment: yes I tried that but it ask all the parameters one by one it doesn't handle the above cases when user provides more than one parameter in single phrase
like if user says "order 2 pepperoni pizza" then agent respond like "which pizza you want?"

Comment: you can make use of Fulfillment where you can write all those conditions and can respond according to the fulfilled condition. Also, you need to train agent for multiple entities in single intent that way only it can extract the extra info if provided.